# Command line interface (or other automation) to publish Customization Project

Tags: acumatica

I am aware that Acumatica has a CLI accessible through ac.exe but when I checked the docs, this seems to support only 'deploy a new application instance
of Acumatica ERP and to perform database and application maintenance'.

Would anyone know if it can also be used to automate publishing of customization projects?

After a source control merge, I would like to automate the following steps:

1. Rebuild dll
2. Open customization project from folder
3. Update modified files (so that dlls are updated in the project)
4. Publish with cleanup to all companies.

Is that possible?

If not available through ac.exe, could it be possible perhaps through .Net code, maybe using the Acumatica SDK or REST API?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific set of web service APIs that you can use to upload and publish packages. This is documented as part of the Customization Guide under *Managing Customization Projects -> To Manipulate Customization Projects form the Code*. Here are the relevant excerpts from the documentation:

**Uploading Packages**

The following code logs in to an Acumatica ERP instance, loads the C:\package1.zip file content, and saves or updates the package1 customization project in the database of the instance.

```
var webserviceurl = "http://localhost/AcumaticaInstance/api/ServiceGate.asmx";
var username = "admin";
var password = "123";
var packageName = "package1";
var packageContents = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\package1.zip");
var replaceIfPackageExists = true;

var client = new ServiceGate.ServiceGate
{
  Url = webserviceurl,
  CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
  Timeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds
};

var loginResult = client.Login(username, password);

if (loginResult.Code == ErrorCode.OK)
{
  client.UploadPackage(packageName, packageContents, replaceIfPackageExists);
}
```

**Publishing Packages**

The following code logs in to an Acumatica ERP instance and publishes the package1, package2, and package3 customization projects that exist in the database of the instance.

```
var webserviceurl = "http://localhost/AcumaticaInstance/api/ServiceGate.asmx";
var username = "admin";
var password = "123";
var packageNames = new []{"package1", "package2", "package3"};
var mergeWithExistingPackages = true;

var client = new ServiceGate.ServiceGate
{
  Url = webserviceurl,
  CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
  Timeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds
};

var loginResult = client.Login(username, password);

if (loginResult.Code == ErrorCode.OK)
{
  client.PublishPackages(packageNames, mergeWithExistingPackages);
}
```

Comment: Should mention there is no option to publish to multi company and no publish errors are reported. (At least from what I have found - please share if you know of any way to do so)

Comment: That would be quite a limitation

Comment: I think to publish for multiple companies, you would need to call the API multiple times (for each time).

Comment: yes but since customizations are not really multi company its just overkill to try the multi site publish by publishing each site separately. Basically for our needs just need the sitemap entry (or any thing that does data insert/update/deletes) and usually testing one company anyhow. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Noted Brendan. Thanks for the info